# Как в Java Swing заменить один компонент на другой при нажатиии на кнопку?

Tags: java

Например кнопку заменить на JLabel. по 2 нажатию на кнопку JLabel должен обратно замениться на кнопку. Каков принцип?

Comment: Сделайте кнопку невидимой при нажатии на нее, а label - наоборот  видимой. А при нажатии на label делайте наоборот. Собственно, всё

Comment: а для чего это вообще?

Comment: зачем вопрос то убрал ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

мне кажется, для таких манипуляций лучше менять стили контролов, а не сами контролы. Я не занимаюсь Java и Swing, поэтому конкретных рецептов, боюсь, вам не дам, но вообще с точки зрения правильного подхода вы должны помнить вот что - кнопка - это некая абстрактная штуковина, которая обладает одним важным свойством - на нее можно нажать, а на нажатие повесить некую логику (обработчик). Так вот это правило касается абсолютно любой кнопки - треугольной, квадратной, круглой или параллельно-перпендикулярной - не важно, как этак кнопка должна выглядеть. А потому вряд ли есть смысл создавать кучу отдельных классов на каждый вид кнопки. Стилевое оформление контролов по-хорошему никогда не должно пересекаться с их логикой. То есть при подобных манипуляциях лучше сменить стиль кнопки, а не саму кнопку - логика у обоих кнопок, насколько я понимаю, одна и та же. Еще раз повторю - не знаю, как это реализовано в Java и Swing, но сам по себе подход с заменой именно кнопок и подкладыванием одной кнопки под другую не очень хорош